# Why does layout_below and layout_above not work but layout_toRightOf does?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I don't want to use a LinearLayout because too many viewgroups is, in my opinion, a waste of memory. So as much as possible I only want to use as few viewgroups as possible.

What happens right now is that the textviews are on top of each other. The EditTexts are also on top of each other. I kinds of need them to be aligned to the baseline of each other too. But the layout_above, and layout_below does not work at all.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.thesis.mobileflowershop.RegisterActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/edittext_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name_label"
    android:hint="@string/username_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_registration" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/name_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/name"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_registration" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/edittext_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/address_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/address_label"
    android:hint="@string/username_hint"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_registration" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/address_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/address"
    android:layout_below="@id/name_label"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_registration" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/contact_no"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/edittext_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/contact_no_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/contact_no_label"
    android:hint="@string/username_hint"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_registration" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/contact_no_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/contact_no"
    android:layout_below="@id/address_label"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_registration" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/edittext_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/username_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/username_label"
    android:hint="@string/username_hint"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_registration" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/username_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/username"
    android:layout_below="@id/contact_no_label"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_registration" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/edittext_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/password_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/password_label"
    android:hint="@string/username_hint"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_registration" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/password_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/password"
    android:layout_below="@id/username_label"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_registration" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email_ad"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/edittext_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/email_ad_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/email_ad_label"
    android:hint="@string/username_hint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_registration" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/email_ad_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/email_ad"
    android:layout_below="@id/password_label"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_registration" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `as much as possible I only want to use as few viewgroups as possible.` It's a **best practice**, to do so. What's your issue? I noticed a sort of recursive references... I prefer to **avoid anticipated references** (as in `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/email_ad"`), and declare the Views in a different order.

Comment: I shouldn't use alignBaseline?

Comment: No, you should. It's the **+** which disturbs me. I'd declare the TextView **after** the EditText. And get rid of the **+**. Do this for **all** the TextView/EditText pairs.

Comment: I'll try that then. Please wait^

Comment: I tried declaring the TextViews after the EditTexts. They are all on top of each other again

Comment: @Der GolemI updated my code above following your suggestion

Comment: I still see this.... `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name_label"`. So, I'd return the TextViews before the EditTexts and instead, move the `android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/name"` to The EditText: `android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/name_label"` So, **after** The TextView is declared, the EditText refers to it. No more **+** s and no more **circular references** (I call you and you call me): only one should reference the other one. Let's say: the EditText references the TextView.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks. You can add an answer and I'll select it

Comment: I have tried the above code any in my system the layout_below is working fine. you can check it again by cleaning up the project.